# Not getting all the services from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The only services i got are

00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb -- Generic Access

00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb -generic attribute

8e400001-f315-4f60-9fb8-838830daea50 -- Buttonless DFU service

0000fee7-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb --

i dont know how to find heart service, calories etc.
the band i am using is Rc-wh10 device name - M2S

MainActivity.java

package iband.bleexample;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@TargetApi(21)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
    TextView tw;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<BluetoothProvider> list;
    iband.bleexample.BluetoothAdapter adapter;
    TextView datatodisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //datatodisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new iband.bleexample.BluetoothAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(MainActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // TODO Handle item click
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        BluetoothDevice bd = new iband.bleexample.BluetoothAdapter(MainActivity.this, list).getDeviceAddress(position);
                        connectToDevice(bd);

                    }
                })
        );


        mHandler = new Handler();
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            scanLeDevice(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mGatt.close();
        mGatt = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Bluetooth not enabled.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
            tw.setText(result.toString());
            // Log.i("result", result.isConnectable()+"");
            //Log.i("result", result.getDevice().getName().toString()+"");
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            list.add(new BluetoothProvider(btDevice.getName(), btDevice.getAddress(), btDevice));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
                tw.setText("ScanResult - Results" + sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
            tw.setText("Scan Failed");
        }
    };

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            tw.setText(device.getName());
                            connectToDevice(device);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
            Log.i("ScanResult - Results", mGatt.toString());
            //scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");

                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.size() + services.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
                Log.i("Services UUID", services.get(i).getUuid() +
                        "");
                for (int j = 0; j < services.get(i).getCharacteristics().size(); j++) {
                    //gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(i).getCharacteristics().get(j));

                    Log.i("Characterstics UUId", services.get(i).getCharacteristics().get(j).getUuid() + "");


                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                                 characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, characteristic.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //gatt.disconnect();
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: What is your specific question here?  Are you not able to discover services or characteristics that you think you should get?  If so, can you post your code where you discover these services?

Comment: Yes, @ScottKronheim i am not able to find heart rate  services only the services mentioned above. but it works with wearfit app and 4fitbit app.

Comment: Not all wearable devices (including wristbands) communicate the same information using the same identifiers (services and characteristics).  There is a list of "standard" GATT service identifiers at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services.  If this wristband does not expose the standard heart rate service identifier, you'll probably need documentation from the wristband manufacturer to identify the specific service(s) and characteristic(s) to use to get what you need.

Comment: There is also a Service named as Nordic UART service , i think it must contain some data. but i dont know how to use it. Also gone through some sniffing stuff but didnt fine any good answers.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes actually these services are hidden or encrypted from the manufacturer . I had to contact them for the documentation to get it resolved.

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I have the same issue with wearfit band.